# Long term monitoring of SMART values

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, smart

I am searching for a free software that runs on Windows 7 and that regularly read the SMART values from my local drives and saves them in a local database for visualization.
Such a software would be really helpful for monitoring the different values, e.g. the Total Bytes Written (TBW) value of a SSD.

Doe anybody know such a software?

I know that smartmontools includes a deamon that can log SMART values. But AFAIR it only outputs text based info and has no database.

Comment: What are you aiming to accomplish?   Your OS is constantly monitoring it, and most SMART events are a one-time trigger when a value is exceeded. So they only change once (good to bad), and then stay in that state until the drive is replaced (or occasionally, repaired).

Comment: Google did a [huge study](http://research.google.com/archive/disk_failures.pdf) on SMART monitoring a while ago.  Perhaps some information in their report would be useful, either for the information you're trying to get or ideas on how they accessed this information.

Comment: @techie007: I am not interested in the good/bad status. More important for me are the tendencies of some values and the absolute TBW value.

Comment: You may have to make your own logging/charting system with a system of batch-files and SMART tools. I guess nobody has bothered to make an advanced SMART tool like this because it is assumed that SMART data isn’t reliable enough, making it of little use. Personally, I don’t care if it’s reliable or not, I just like the data, logs, and charts. `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you don't need to be constantly monitoring the SMART status? Periodic checking would be sufficient I would think. It's not like the output is that accurate for predicting failure anway - check out the Google report referenced by @jbarlow, also check what Steve Gibson has to say about SMART in his article ["SMART is dumb"](http://www.grc.com/sn/SN-081.txt).

If this is the case, why not run the smartmon tool periodically, run the text output through a script to capture the required output into a table - text-based might well be sufficient. Then use a spreadsheet to process the table.

You could further refine this so that the output was processed into a simple database such as sqlite. Any of the scripting languages would be able to do this - In order of personal preference: Node.js, PHP, Python, PERL. A 2nd script would periodically rifle through the database and produce an appropriate log - perhaps in HTML format with a suitable chart.

In fact, thinking further, if all you are interested in is how much data has been read/written in order to try and predict SSD failure, I'd run a periodic script (once a week would be more than enough), just capture the TBW and anything else needed and, if it is above a given threshold, write to syslog and raise a system or external mail alert.

Comment: *> If this is the case, why not run the smartmon tool periodically, run the text output through a script to capture the required output*   That's exactly what I have been doing (with [SmartUDM](http://www.sysinfolab.com/download.htm)) for years now. I have a folder full of timestamp-named files with all the SMART data of my drives. I don't do it as frequently anymore because it's a chore, but when I do, I (manually) compare the new file(s) to the previous one to see the "progress". I agree that an actual program would be much better.

Comment: @Synetech: You can, of course, get smartmontools for Windows so creating an AT job or better a Windows scheduler job to run once a week should be easy enough, just a simple batch file. The processing could be a separate job of course. I must admit though, it seems too much of a faff even for an endemic automator like me to be bothered with ;) Better to keep things backed up and enjoy the surprise shopping trip when things fail! ;)

Comment: Even if this is not the answer I was hoping for it is still the best answer...

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely free, but I've used [ArgusMonitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArgusMonitor) for that purpose. Might do what you need. If not, try googling "argusmonitor free alternative graph" or somesuch.

Comment: Does it really allow to monitor smart values for several months? The screen shots only show monitoring for the last minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a product that logs the drive's history, but I do know of a product that does long-term monitoring of the health of the drive and gives alerts in real-time.

The product is [HDDLife](http://hddlife.com/index.html), which has [three versions](http://hddlife.com/eng/compare.html) : freeware, commercial €20, commercial €22.

[image]

Comment: *>  I do know of a product that does long-term monitoring of the health of the drive... HDDLife*   What is the long-term aspect?

Comment: @Synetech: It's not a utility I use, although it's well-referenced (more than 1 million on google). It's evident that it keeps a record of issues over time when computing the health or degradation of a disk.

Comment: *> It's evident that it keeps a record of issues over time when computing the health or degradation of a disk.*   Not to me; [all I can find](http://hddlife.com/eng/features.html) is that it reads the *current* SMART data.

Comment: @Synetech: Yah, it's quite difficult to find any facts inside that commercial bla-bla. That is why I chose the screenshot above, where a new disk is being shown as somewhat unhealthy after only 3+ months. By my logic (which might be flawed) nothing else than high and sustained temperatures or high sector-failure rate (even if mapped to spare sectors) can cause such a prognostic.

Comment: Yes, but it is still reading the *current* SMART data; there is nothing historical or long-term about it, so it is no different than any other SMART-capable program.

Comment: *> By my logic (which might be flawed) nothing else than high and sustained temperatures or high sector-failure rate (even if mapped to spare sectors) can cause such a prognostic.*   Dropped a non-SSD? Flood? Alien—HD-autopsy?

Comment: @Synetech: You continue like that and I'm going to have nightmares tonight.

Comment: That’s nothing; I’m constantly paranoid about my drives. Every time I hear the slightest tick sound I worry that my drive has the click of death. I fear moving laptops or even going near them for fear of bumping it and causing a head-crash. I know they are more resilient than that (Scott Mueller used to open a drive and press his finger on the platter to bend it while it’s spinning to demonstrate that it still worked afterwards—but that was a long time ago with old drives), but I worry anyway because they *do* fail. Unfortunately SSDs solve that problem but have a whole new one.